Homotopy equivalence between the complement of an open disc and the complement of a point
Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional connected smooth manifold and let $p\in M$. Is it true that if $V$ is a coordinate ball centered at $p$, then $M-V$ is (smoothly) homotopy equivalent to $M-p$?
Just to give you some context, this is part of a question of finding the DeRham cohomology of the complement of a torus $T^2-D$ where $D$ is an open disk. Intuitively, $T^2-D\simeq T^2-p$, because it's like reversing the retraction from $D$ to $p$, and I know the cohomology of $T^2-p$. So I was hoping that they are homotopy equivalent.
(Bad) Attempt: For the $M=\mathbb{R}^n$ case, consider $\mathbb{R}^n-0\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n,x\mapsto x/||x||$. Now, initially I thought it was "obvious" that this was a homotopy equivalence but now I'm not too sure. Similarly, I had $\mathbb{R}^n-B^0_1(0)\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^n,x\mapsto x/||x||$. Now, I think If I can show one is, then the other would be.

Assume wlog that $\overline W\setminus V\subset M$ is homeomorphic, via some coordinate chart $\varphi$, to $\overline{D(0,3)}\setminus D(0,1)$. The intermediate subset $U:=\varphi(D(0,2))$ is then open.
Let us first prove that the natural inclusion
$$i:A:=\overline{D(0,3)}\setminus D(0,1)\hookrightarrow B:=\overline{D(0,3)}\setminus\{0\}$$
is a homotopy equivalence with every point of the subset $C:=\overline{D(0,3)}\setminus D(0,2)$ fixed.
For this purpose, using spherical coordinates, we just need to prove the corresponding property for the natural inclusion
$$j:[1,3]\hookrightarrow(0,3].$$
Let
$$g:(0,3]\to[1,3]$$ be some smooth strictly increasing function leaving every point of $[2,3]$ fixed. Then, $j\circ g$ is homotopic to ${\rm id}_{(0,3]}$ (with every point of $[2,3]$ fixed), via
$$H:(0,3]\times[0,1]\to(0,3],\quad(r,t)\mapsto (1-t)g(r)+tr,
$$
and $g\circ j$ is homotopic to ${\rm id}_{[1,3]}$ via the restriction
$[1,3]\times[0,1]\to[1,3]$ of this homotopy.
This homotopy equivalence $(j,g,H)$ corresponds via $\varphi$ to a  homotopy equivalence $(k,h,F)$ between $\overline W\setminus V$ and $\overline W\setminus\{p\}$, leaving every point of $\overline W\setminus U$ fixed. This $(k,h,F)$ extends to a (smooth) homotopy equivalence between $M\setminus V$ and $M\setminus\{p\}$, by gluing it to the identity on $M\setminus U$.

Is this a homotopy equivalence between the pairs $(M\setminus V,M\setminus U)$ and $(M\setminus p,M\setminus U)$?

It is more that that: it does not simply map $M\setminus U$ into itself; it leaves fixed each point of $M\setminus U$.

Does it also hold that $M\setminus p$ deformation retracts to $M\setminus V$? I would think that the argument is similar.

Rather to $M\setminus\overline V$.

Another question, I'm very sorry. Are $(M-p,(M-p)\cap W)$ and $(M-V,\partial (M-V))$ homotopy equivalent, where $W$ is a coordinate ball containing the regular coordinate ball $V$ and $p\in V$?

Yes they are. Hint: check that $((0,3],(0,2),{3})$ and $([1,3],{1},{3})$ are homotopy equivalent.

@Porcupine Sorry, no idea. I don't even know what the skeleton of a manifold is.
